# How to make hover buttons?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a CSS class so that i can use it like this

```
<input type="button" class="hoverbuttons">
```

So how do I make a class so that my button will hover?

I have two buttons already. Assuming those URLs to be URL1 and URL2 how can I make them hover-able using CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites). You'll need to change the `<input>` tags to `<a>` tags:

```
<style>

a.link1 {
display:block;
height:10px;
background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}

a.link1:hover {
background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat 0 -10px;
}

</style>

<a href="URL1" class="link1">foo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tutorials in the web:

- [CSS Hover Dynamic Button](http://www.leon-zinger.com/css-tricks/create-css-hover-dynamic-button-).

Comment: Yeah, the same way you do on anchor 1, do on the other....or did I understand you wrong?

Comment: No,I want to hover a button using two separate images with two differnet URLs

Comment: ok, then you create another class for anchor 2 with its respective hover. It's basically a clone of what you do in anchor 1 except with a different class name (and css).

Answer (score 0):

just apply these rules:

```
.hoverbuttons { ... }
.hoverbuttons:hover { ... }
```

note: on IE6 and previous `:hover` pseudoclass will work only on `<a>` elements.

Comment: To fix IE6, use the Whatever:Hover hack -- http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html

Comment: ok, in that case he will face another problem, that is how to define a specific style for that hovered element, since ´.hoverbuttons.hover´ is not a recognized expression on IE6. He may need some extra class on ancestor element

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pixelmill.com/support/support_article.aspx?ParentListID=al1015&articleid=kb101543

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .some {
      background-color:#0F9;
  }

  .some:hover {
      background-color:#F00;
  }  
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="some"> dsadsad </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Nothing happened when i hover !!

Comment: @Elite - the hover issue in IE only applies to older versions (IE6); newer versions do work. But even with older versions, hover can be made to work in IE using a well known hack: http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html

Comment: i think we need csshover.htc hack file to make it work like this in ie6